# Need to press button twice, first to close keyboard second to send. How do I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a case where I have users that can enter text in a field for a mobile web site.

They then need to press a button to send the message but they have to press it twice, once to close the keyboard and the second to send the message.

The sending is taking place via JQuery Ajax fired from an event handler. I have preventDefault on if that matters.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: May be you have to use a counter to determinate how many times user pressed the button

Comment: @JorgeMejia I don't think he wants them to have to press twice, that's the problem he's trying to fix.

Comment: let the form submit when enter is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the focus from the input on button click to hide the software keyboard:

```
$("input").blur();
```

Comment: This might be the solution. Not at my system at the moment but will post back if this is the problem.